# Does webgl work on chrome on a mac?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, webgl, osx-mountain-lion

I got webgl to work on safari, but can't get it to work on chrome. I use this to test

http://get.webgl.org/

On safari, it works only after enabling webgl, see http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11926

On chrome, it says "Hmm. While your browser seems to support WebGL, it is disabled or unavailable. If possible, please ensure that you are running the latest drivers for your video card"

I was hoping there might be a way to enable webgl in chrome the way it's enabled in safari.

I am on Mac OS X 10.8.2, using Macbook pro retina (NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M),
Chrome version 24.0.1312.57.  My video card is not on a blacklist (but not on any whitelist, either) www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/BlacklistsAndWhitelists

Comment: Chrome works - just like Safari - after upgrading to 25.0.1364.99

Answer (score 25):

Enable "Use hardware acceleration when available" in the Chrome settings.

I had the same problem on a mid-2012 Macbook Air. Here's how I fixed it.

- Go to chrome://settings/
- "Show advanced settings" (link at the bottom)
- System (second-to-last at the bottom)
- Enabled the checkbox for "Use hardware acceleration when available."
- Restart Chrome (required for me)

Comment: I am having the same issue as OP but this was already enabled for me.

Answer (score 8):

Having the same issue today on a MB with OSX 1.7.5. I guess that there are many reasons why Webgl could be unsupported. Having your OS/browser updated does not mean your system (i.e. your graphic card) does support webgl. Try opening `chrome://gpu/` in Chrome and read through the problems detected.

More on this [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1220892?hl=en).

Answer (score 8):

Time has passed and Chrome got to version 54 so I thought I could add an update (and group some of the answers around here):

1. First of all, make sure that hardware acceleration is enabled in the advanced settings (as [Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29710846/4375377) mentioned).
2. Check `chrome://gpu` to get an idea what the problem might be. Under **Problems detected**, you get quite some information that can point you in the right direction.
3. Do not panic if you can't find the `#Disable-WebGL` flag anymore, because they got rid of it.
4. If you find something like

   > GPU process was unable to boot: All GPU features are blacklisted. 
   >   Disabled Features: all

   under **Problems detected** and you are sure it used to work in earlier versions of chrome, you might consider to enable `#ignore-gpu-blacklist` under `chrome://flags` with extreme caution!

Comment: query: what do you mean by "with extreme caution"? I have a 8 year old MacBookPro and I would like to see that WebGL plays on Google Chrome, but is there a chance this will actually destroy my computar?

Comment: @esaruoho There is a reason why these GPUs have been blacklisted. I think it should not be a problem for basic WebGL, but more advanced features might not be implemented correctly and in the worst case corrupt your system (although I think it is pretty unlikely that would happen). I think you should not be afraid that your computer will start to burn (unless you have severe hardware issues).

Answer (score 6):

Maybe just enable the "Override software rendering list" (#ignore-gpu-blacklist) :

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/150212/hardware-acceleration-for-flash-videos-in-google-chrome

It fixed this bug for me on OS X 10.9.5, Chrome v38.0.2125.101

Answer (score 2):

Chrome definitely supports WebGL on OSX, and I can confirm that your Mac should work just fine. (I use one to develop WebGL in Chrome!)

It sounds as if you may have accidentally disabled it somehow? Check in chrome://flags and see if "Disable WebGL" flag has been set. Also, take a peek at chrome://gpu and see if it's showing any messages indicating why WebGL may be disabled.

Comment: It does not fix the problem, unfortunately. I myself am on Mac OS X 10.6.8 (AMD Radeon HD 6750M), Chrome version 27.0.1453.116.

Comment: I also fail to get webgl to work on mac osx. Really frustrating! 
osx 10.9 mac book pro

Answer (score 1):

"Maybe just enable the "Override software rendering list" (#ignore-gpu-blacklist)"

This worked for me in Chrome Version 47.0.2526.73 (64-bit) with OS X 10.7.5 (a 2007 Mac Pro).

Answer (score 0):

If WebGL isn't currently enabled, you can head to your Chrome Flags settings in your browser: chrome://flags/

Update the Override software rendering list to enabled. This should be near the top of the list